# Azure Data Studio won't open on Red Hat Enterprise Linux 9

Tags: linux, installation, redhat-enterprise-linux, azure-data-studio

I am attempting to use Azure Data Studio on a Red Hat Enterprise Linux 9 server. I followed [Microsoft's instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/azure-data-studio/download-azure-data-studio?view=sql-server-ver16&tabs=redhat-install%2Credhat-uninstall) for installing it. The install succeeded; however, when I try to use the `azuredatastudio` command to open it, nothing happens. Literally nothing - no error message, no messages in the terminal, nothing opens:
[image]

When I run `ps aux` command, there doesn't appear to be any process running that's even remotely related to Azure Data Studio.

Has anyone encountered this issue? Does anyone know steps I could take to fix this, or at least some way that I could find more information on what the problem is?

As further context (if this is relevant), I am currently using the command line exclusively (not the GUI). I recently ran

```
sudo yum groupinstall "Server with GUI"
```

to install the GUI. This ran successfully; however, I don't have root access to use any of the `systemctl` commands suggested in [this article](https://linuxconfig.org/install-gnome-gui-on-rhel-7-linux-server) to be able to actually open the UI. Do I need to get this working in order to be able to actually use Azure Data Studio? (If so, I guess that would need to be a separate question to avoid this one being too broad).

**Edit:** If I try `sudo azuredatastudio`, I get

> You are trying to start Azure Data Studio as a super user which isn't recommended. If this was intended, please add the argument `--no-sandbox` and specify an alternate user data directory using the `--user-data-dir` argument.

On the plus side, this means that the binary apparently is responding to *something* at least. Unfortunately, if I try

```
sudo azuredatastudio --no-sandbox --user-data-dir test
```

it still doesn't work.

Trying `which azuredatastudio` returns `/usr/bin/azuredatastudio`, so the binary is definitely installed.